# How can compute rolling window for standard deviation in R?

Tags: r, stock, standard-deviation

I tried to download the stock price and compute the standard deviation in rolling window. I found the library `PerformanceAnalytics` but they only have the rolling window for Mean not standard deviation.

```
library("tseries")
library("zoo")
library("forecast")
library("FinTS")
library("rugarch")


AAL.data = get.hist.quote(instrument="AAL", start="2014-01-01",  end="2018-01-01", quote="AdjClose", provider="yahoo", compression="d", retclass="zoo")
plot(AAL.data, main = "AAL closing price", ylab = "Price (USD)", xlab = "Date")

#install.packages("PerformanceAnalytics")
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
chart.RollingMean(XOM.sr, width = 60, xaxis = TRUE, ylim = NULL)
```

Comment: Check out `roll_sd` and `roll_sdr` from package `RcppRoll`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(zoo)
rollapplyr(1:10, 3, sd, fill = NA)
## [1] NA NA  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

See `?rollapply` for more info.

Answer (score 1):

For who is looking for this nowdays, use `roll_sd` of `roll` package ([rdrr.io link](https://rdrr.io/cran/roll/man/roll_sd.html)).

```
                          expr        min         lq        mean   median        uq        max neval
 rollapply(STK, width = 5, sd) 34703.2817 37535.3761 40422.77272 38005.02 38357.489 53512.7018     5
               roll_sd(STK, 5)    18.9334    18.9973    23.90904    19.14    30.608    31.8665     5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete reproducible example. You can use `runSD` for this of the `TTR` package. It integrates very well with `xts`.
Normally you would first compute returns and then the std. deviation of this to represent risk.

```
library(quantmod)
library(TTR)

AAPL = getSymbols("AAPL", auto.assign = FALSE)

returns = ROC(Ad(AAPL), n=1)[-1]

plot(runSD(returns, n=30), main='Rolling Std. Deviation (30 days)')
```